# Which data properties need to change to trigger an update?

Tags: html, vue.js

I am practicing vue js. This is the vue.js code

```
new Vue({
 el: '#people',
 data: {
  var1: 0,
  var2: null,
  var3: 'Hello',
  var4: 'Yassss'
 },
 computed: {
  var5: function() {
  let var1 = 0;
  if(this.var2 != null){
    var1++;
  }
  console.log(this.var3);
  return var1;
 }
}
});
```

This is the html code

```
<p>{{ var5 }}</p>
```

The thing I am trying to understand is which data properties would need to change to trigger an update to the page

Currently it is giving out the following output:

```
{{ var5 }}
```

I tried changing all of them in different combinations but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

A computed is used mainly to trigger changes regarding what it's returning, hence if you return `var1`, you should mutate it somewhere in your code (`v-model`, `this.var1 = ...` etc).

Keep in mind that using a conditional like `this.var2 != null` doesn't have a lot of meaning because the `computed()` will not be "called" until `var1` is updated.
I recommend reading [the documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) once again to understand which use cases are good for a `computed()`.

---

Something like this have more sense

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ welcomeSomebody }}</p>
    <p>username: <input v-model="username" type="text" /></p>
    <p>how to greet: <input v-model="greet" type="text" /></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      greet: 'hello',
      username: 'bob',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    welcomeSomebody() {
      return `${this.greet} ${this.username}`
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

[image]